# Glassfish timeout

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish

When a try to start glassfish from within Eclipse the following error occurs:

> Unable to start server on time. java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException

And when a try to start via `asadmin start-domain` or `asadmin start-domain domain1` it remains loading and never stops.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform the following two steps:

1. Go to the folder where you store the Glasfish.
   Example: My folder is `C:\Program Files (x86)\glassfish-4.0\glassfish\bin`.
2. Double click on `startserv.bat` and wait a few seconds and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it like the following :

1. try to update the GlassFish tools from the Eclipse MarketPlace, and
   get the latest update ,  and check eclipse for any updates .
2. restart Eclipse , "I don't know why , but it works " .

Comment: I've tried updating the tool but it says nothing to update and the issue remains same.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue with my **Glassfish 4.0** server, I did googled but didn't worked out for me.

You can manually deploy your web application by exporting your project as .war file and then using Glassfish GUI (http://localhost:4848) deploy your application and then access it.

Answer (score 1):

Open the GlassFish Server configuration by double clicking on your server instance in your server windows. You shall find a Timeout section. Expand it and increase the time limit to complete server operations in the Start section. This should work.